# You don't have permission to access [ Apache + CentOS 6.3 ]

Tags: linux, centos

If I paste the code from a file into index.html and try to access it from browser is working BUT if I try to transfer the file with WinSCP into /var/www/html directory I get "403 Forbidden; You don't have permission to access". I also tried to copy the file with root login or a user made without root access + chown the /var/www/html directory to root, apache, nothing worked. What could be the problem?

Comment: In general on CentOS: SELinux security contexts. Try for instance [`restorecon -R /var/www/html/`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon)

Comment: It worked! thanks, can u please reply as an answer so I can mark as the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frequently such problems find their origin in SELinux security context violations.

Try for instance [`restorecon -R /var/www/html/`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon)

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. Add the below code.

```
<Directory "path">
  #Options FollowSymLinks
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then, restart `httpd`.